# Pygame for Python 3.5.1 (Nothing I've tried has worked)

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.5

I've been trying to install pygame for Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10, 64 bit. Everything I've attempted so far has resulted in an error message in some form.
My latest attempt has been when I downloaded pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (also tried the 32-bit, got same error) from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame and dragged the .whl file into Python35-32/Scripts. I then proceeded to go to command prompt and do the pip install thing, to which I got this message: 
   "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64"

I am aware that I may be installing it incorrectly, but from my understanding of other guides, this is what they say to have done. I would greatly appreciate help if possible.

Comment: @zondo: The OP clearly said they're using Windows; `apt-get` is only for certain Linux flavors.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've left the file extension off of the filename when you're calling `pip install`. Make sure you include the `.whl` extension, of pip will think the file name is the name of a package it should be downloading for you.

Comment: Hmm... Just tried that and it said: Requirement 'pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl' (Same thing for 64 bit, just with the 64 bit's file name) looks like a filename, but the file does not exist. pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32 is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I am placing the .whl file in Python/Python35-32/Scripts. Is this the wrong place? Do I need to do anytthing else?

Comment: It doesn't matter where exactly you put the `.whl` file, but you need to pass its path properly to `pip` or it won't find it. I just downloaded the 64-bit pygame installer you linked to and installing it worked for me. I opened a command prompt and ran `path-to-python\Scripts\pip.exe install path-to-my-downloads-folder\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` (I have 64-bit Python installed).

Comment: Got an error message saying "This system can't find the path specified." I tried this with both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Edit: I reread what you said and I'll try something else. I'll update this if it works.

Comment: Well, it sure sounds like you're not writing the path correctly. Can you edit the question with the exact command you're using? If you right click on a command prompt window, you can choose "mark" from the "edit" submenu, then click and drag to select something. Enter copies. (Why the windows command prompt doesn't use decent shortcut keys like everything else, I have no idea).

Comment: path-to-python35-32\Scripts\pip.exe install path-to-python35-32\Scripts\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl (Made this based on what you had, not completely sure of everything you did)

Comment: those "path-to" bits were abstracting out the details of my system (I have strage drives letters). Are you actually using the correct paths for your system?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. This is the first time I'm doing anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is not compatible with python 3.5. But it is with python 3.4. You can find binaries at: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads

For previous version of python: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that you have the 64 bit version of Python (the default windows download is 32bit). If not, here's the link:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/

When you have the 64 bit python going, From the command prompt / Powershell, use  "pip install pygame" or "python -m pip install pygame" then you will be sure the os, python, and pygame are all 64bit, mixing and matching doesn't work.